# Multiple possible templates in a class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to have a class which can be created with either a type or an array. I am not sure if templates are the best way to do this but I thought they might work. In the below code example, I have a class which has two static methods who both return an instance of the class based on the template they are given:

```
template<class T>
template<class A, size_t N>
class Foo {
    static A[N] bar();
    static T bar();
}

template<class A, size_t N>
Foo<A[N]> Foo<A[N]>::bar();

template<class T>
Foo<T> Foo<T>::bar();
```

So I can call them like this:

```
Foo<int[5]> intarrthing Foo<int[5]>::bar();
Foo<int> intthing Foo<int>::bar();
```

This doesn't work because not all the templates are used so how could I implement something like this?

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore and an uppercase character are reserved for use by the standard C++ library.

Comment: Please note that symbols beginning with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_Tp` or `_A_tp`) are reserved in all scopes for the implementation (compiler and standard library). Please see [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for details.

Comment: Sorry about that. I can update my question. Thanks for the link @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: How doesn't work? What errors do you see? The first two lines also look suspicious having a `template` of a `template`.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain exactly what you're trying to do. But note that if you define a `template <class T> class Foo`... using just `T` and then use `Foo<int[5]>`, then the parameter `T` *is* an array type within the `Foo` definition.

Comment: I wanted to be able to have two different functions for the different templates (handle arrays differently from "normal" types). What you suggested works completely fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions cannot differ only by return type (except functions template).

From your usage, you might simply do:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {
    static Foo<T> bar() { return {}; }
};


Foo<int[5]> intarrthing = Foo<int[5]>::bar();
Foo<int> intthing = Foo<int>::bar();
```

Comment: Indeed. `A<N>` can be a `T`. OP seemed to expect that an array type wasn't a type.